# Is it correct to use the present participle to describe what something does rather than only describing/modifying its current state?

Tags: grammar

For example:

> It is a thing that works producing stuff.

This feels wrong to me, but I can't quite put my finger on what exactly is wrong about it. It seems like it's trying to be a participle phrase, but it's not necessarily modifying the current state of "it", and is, instead, describing what "it" is -- i.e. by working, "it" produces stuff.

If it is, indeed, a participle phrase, then it should be able to be written as

> Producing stuff, it is a thing that works.

But, to me, this doesn't seem correct either, so it leads me to believe that the very structure of the sentence is incorrect.

Comment: I can imagine either "works by producing stuff", or "spends its time producing stuff", or "works producing stuff for sale".   Maybe it's the meaning that doesn't quite gel for "works producing stuff".

Comment: "It is a thing that works producing stuff" sounds odd but I don't think it's ungrammatical. It's meaningless, perhaps. You do identify a confusion over what it means, but that's not really something we can tell you. Is "producing stuff" supposed to describe something it does at the same time as working (participle phrase), or is it the output of working (which would be an -ing form functioning as the object or complement of a verb, not a participle phrase)? Compare "he works gritting roads for the council".

Comment: Could the sentence be parallel to “Paper clips work **for** holding pages together” or to “Glues work **by** chemically bonding two objects together”?

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by *works*.  You might say "He is retired but she works, selling houses" but this may not be what you intend.

Comment: Producing woodchips is how that machine works.

Comment: @Lambie I wonder whether you wouldn't be making  an inappropriate amalgamation of "how" and "what" in your thinking.

Comment: A present participle can certainly describe a thing's typical function, regardless of whether it is performing that function at the moment.  For example, a holding tank may be empty, a reclining chair may be upright, and a working man may be on a break.

Comment: Why not just "It is a thing that produces stuff"?

Comment: @LPH Funny but the second I saw "inappropriate amalgamation" I knew it was you.

Comment: @Lambie On the grounds of your impression being genuine it becomes interresting to learn what triggers it.

Answer (score 5):

As LPH says, 'work making/doing/building/washing/sewing ...' is an idiomatic and quite productive construction.

A [formal] paraphrase of say 'He works delivering pizzas' is 'His work entails delivering pizzas'.

Obviously, a volitional agent as subject is normal.

However, broadened usage gives rise to examples such as

- *This specialised machine works making rows and each active organ can copy the soil surface and has 1.8 m width of work*. [[FISITA](https://go.fisita.com/store/papers/conat99/Hermenean_I_1-?search=53616c7465645f5f13de2f93511c1982cd28105af1f8a74ae04b84fd6769654454d7338adfc5506342d90121403d2c9a2f4b612f5c9f621171dd9d2af62815d69f4c28a69090a87e5550c6ee48237b76299831ea8ce3ec5ddfe0ff83e0f77b89ea2f86f67d4c072ca5bc610bbe887311b58128a6c41ff9b71afe47ab3da873e96691a6b3ef5cd1fa)]
- *A Turing machine works handling symbols without assigning any meaning to them.* [[ResearchGate](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Can_anyone_prove_whether_or_not_it_possible_that_a_computer-like_machine_can_detect_expressions_like_sadness_or_identify_pictures_at_different_ages)]

These appear to be quite rare; they could be deletions of 'by', or echoing the normal examples using personification and a switch in sense (work = perform their function).

Answer (score 4):

This sentence is not grammatically correct. There appears to be in it a confusion between the idioms "work doing something" and "work making something" as meaning both "to have a job doing something" and "work" as meaning "to function"; there is no "[V + V-ing]" pattern for this meaning of "work".

Here is a whole lot of examples of use of the idioms: [doing](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22he%20works%20doing%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en), [making](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22he%20works%20making%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en).

- <s>It is a thing that works producing stuff.</s>
- It is a thing whose work is to produce stuff.